# Rails remote form collection_select onchange error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to have a remote form automatically submit when a select option is changed. Everything works when I remove `remote: true` from the form tag, except I don't want the page to reload each time.

I am using Rails 5.1.4.

**Code**

```
<%= form_for @foo, remote: true do |f| %>

    ... fields

    <%= f.collection_select :bar_id, @list, :id, :name,
       {include_blank: '-'}, { onchange: 'this.form.submit();'} %>

<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @foo.update(foo_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @foo }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @foo }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @foo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting the following error when the selection is updated in the view:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

I'm assuming the `this.form.submit();` is the problem. How can I get this form to submit successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to the following simple way adding `authenticity_token: true` to your form tag like below

```
<%= form_for @foo, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
```

It should work, at least working for me.

**Updated After Comment**

You need to work with partial if you use `remote: true` like if your form in `new.html.erb` then cut out form part and create a partial for the form like `_form.html.erb` then render this into `new.html.erb` like

`new.html.erb`

```
<div id="my-form">
   <%= render partial: "form" %>
</div>
```

and the create a `js.erb` file based your main file like `new.js.erb` and put this line like

```
$("#my-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("form")) %>");
```

On your controller add `format.js` like below

```
format.html { redirect_to @foo } 
format.js 
format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @foo }
```

For complete `jQuery/AJAX` reference with RoR-5 you can read [this tutorial](https://rubyplus.com/articles/4211-Using-Ajax-and-jQuery-in-Rails-5-Apps) it will help to brush up your `jQuery/AJAX` skill

Hope that will work

Comment: That seemed to fix the error from displaying, however the page is still reloading when the selection is changed. I updated the original post to include the controller action code.

Comment: @Matt See the updated answer, you need to create a partial form for work with ajax form submit without reloading the whole page, I have described step by step please follow this then I hope you will achieve your goal

Comment: I have made those changes. Everything is working but the page still reloads. In the console I'm getting a `Redirected to ...` message. Is the `format.html { redirect_to @foo }` line in the controller causing this?

Comment: @Matt use `format.js { redirect_to @foo }` to your controller action

Comment: I replaced the `format.html { redirect_to @foo }` with `format.js { redirect_to @foo }` in the controller and now am getting a `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error.

Comment: Ok, not need to replacing you follow just this `format.html { redirect_to @foo }
    format.js
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @foo }`

Comment: @Matt See the below of my answer

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your form.

```
<%= tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, :value => form_authenticity_token) %>
```

and your form should be like this:

```
   <%= form_for @foo, remote: true do |f| %>
        <%= tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, :value => form_authenticity_token) %>
        ... fields

        <%= f.collection_select :bar_id, @list, :id, :name,
           {include_blank: '-'}, { onchange: 'this.form.submit();'} %>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The authenticity token is a random value generated in your view to prove a request is submitted from a form on your site, not somewhere else. This protects against CSRF attacks

You can avoid above error by two ways

1) Add following code in application controller

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

Reference Link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html

2) Add `authenticity_token` in the form

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

OR `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`